# An example of a noetherian N-1 ring that is not N-2 and/or a Nagata ring

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Hello is there anyone that would know where I can find an example of a noetherian N-1 ring that is not a Nagata ring. (See the Wikipedia article "[Nagata ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagata_ring)" for the definitions of N-1 ring and Nagata ring.)

Comment: Did you check Nagata's "Local rings"? 

Comment: The title does not make sense... 

Comment: there is no counter example to the above question in Nagata's Local rings I checked

Comment: There is such a counter example on pages 206 - 207.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a discrete valuation ring $R$ (hence trivially N-1) of characteristic $p>0$ whose completion $\widehat{R}$ contains an element $x\not\in R$ such that $x^p\in R$. Such a ring cannot be N-2.

Comment: I dont understand why such a ring cannot be n-2 furthermore why must we look at the completion to find such an x i mean why not take x= y^(1/p) where y $in$ R

Comment: A discrete valuation ring $R$ has finite integral closure $S$ in the finite extension $L$ of the fraction field $K=\mathrm{Frac}(R)$ if and only if:

\[
\sum\limits_{w|v}e(w|v)f(w|v)=[L:K]
\]

where $v$ is the valuation associated to $R$ and the sum is taken over all extensions of $v$ to $L$. For $L=K(x)$ with $x\in\widehat{R}\setminus R$ and $x^p\in R$  the following facts are known: there is only one extension $w$ of $v$ to $L$ ($L/K$ is purely inseparable). The equations $e(w|v)=f(w|v)=1$ holds, because the completion is unramified over $R$ and has the same residue field as $R$.